# Definition of a subobject n a category

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, definition

A sub-object of an object $A$ in a category is an equivalence class of monomorphisms $s:U \to A$, where $s$ is equivalent to another monomorphism $t:V \to A$ if there exist morphisms $x:U \to V$, $y:V \to U$ such that 
$$
s = t \circ x, ~~~~~~~~~\text{ and  } t = s \circ y.
$$

Consider now the alternative definition, where we require $x$, or equivalently $y$ to be isomorphisms. This is clearly more restrictive. What is a good example to illustrate the fact the the first definition is the more natural one to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the two definitions are equivalent.

Given the existence of those morphisms $x$ and $y$, substituting $t= s \circ y$ into the equation $s = t \circ x$ gives $s= s \circ y \circ x$. Since $s$ is a monomorphism, we have that $y \circ x = id_U$.

Similarly, we can prove $x \circ y= id_V$.

Therefore $x$ and $y$ are isomorphisms with each other as their inverse.

Comment: Great, I guess sometimes life is easy!

Comment: One thing though, if we have a different monomorphism $x':U \to A$, such that $x \neq x' \circ f$, for some endomorphism of $U$, then the definition implies that this is a different subobject. Can such an $x'$ exist?

Comment: Such $x'$s are common and expected. In the category of sets, take a monomorphism $f:U\to A$ that is not surjective, and change the output of any single $u\in U$ to any element of $A$ not already in the image of $f$.

Comment: @JuandelaSelva In the category of abelian groups, all the nonzero subobjects of $\mathbb{Z}$ can be represented by a monomorphism $\phi_n:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}:z\to nz$ for some natural number $n$, but they are really different subobjects.